# Amount of allowed subdomains in domain and email

Tags: email, domain, subdomain

How many subdomains can you have on your domain? And with that, I mean levels of subdomains.

For example, you have the domain `example.com`, I know you can have `test.example.com`, but how many levels can you have? Like `test2.test.example.com`, `test3.test2.test.example.com` etc.

Second, I was wondering 2 things about email addresses. First of all, how common is the usage of subdomains in an email address (IF it's even possible)? I've never seen something like `test@test.example.com` to be honest so I'm not exactly sure. And if it's possible, how many levels (just like above) can you have?

And last, can the questions above depend on the domain registrar or the mail server etc.? And what could it depend on?

Comment: It's very common in countries like Australia and the UK which have `.com.au` and `.co.uk` to have three levels in the hostname in email addresses.

Comment: @Nacht: Indeed, that can pretty easily get you to something like `smith@foonly.maths.ox.ac.uk`

Comment: Yeah I forgot about that. How could I've forgot. I see `.com` and `.nl` too much I forgot about the other extensions like `com.au`, `.co.uk` etc etc.

Comment: For the record, I used to have an e-mail address `@cgg.ms.mff.cuni.cz`. Deep domain hierarchies are rather common in academia.

Comment: @Angew Oh, well I've never seen something like it so I didn't know it is possible.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There are no direct limits on how many levels i.e. dots you can have in a hostname. However, a [RFC1034](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034) compliant hostname can only be **255** bytes long, leaving **253** bytes for a *fully qualified domain name* FQDN in DNS. Some systems and TLS/SSL limits FQDN to **64** bytes and FQDN in emails should not exceed(*) **245** or **221** or **189** bytes depending on the maximum user name length (8, 32 or 64).

As TLD usually takes at least 2 characters and `.` and every part of the hostname must be at least one character long, the space left for additional dots i.e. **theoretically maximal** levels would be:

- (253-3)/2 = 125 levels after TLD for theoretically longest (not so useful) hostname
- (221-3)/2 = 109 or (189-3)/2 = 93 levels after TLD, if you wish to use it for email
- (63-3)/2 = 30 levels after TLD, if you wish to use SSL/TLS.

And yes, `user@subdomainof.subdomain.example.com` is in a valid email address format.

---

(*) The special limitation for email address length is a result of RFC 5321 [4.5.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.5.3.1) and [4.1.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-4.1.2):

```
4.5.3.1.1.  Local-part

   The maximum total length of a user name or other local-part is 64
   octets.

4.5.3.1.3.  Path

   The maximum total length of a reverse-path or forward-path is 256
   octets (including the punctuation and element separators).

4.1.2 Command Argument Syntax

   Path           = "<" [ A-d-l ":" ] Mailbox ">"
```

As forward-path must include the angle brackets, only 254 characters are left for the email address. Then, the `username@` part of 8(+1), 32(+1) or 64+1 must be excluded to get the maximum FQDN lenght.

Comment: [RFC 1034](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc1034) is where the  upper limit on both the total length of the domain name (including all the subdomain parts) of 255 octets originates from and as well as the maximum length of 63 octets for a hostname/subdomain. Longer domain names should (rather than must) be supported as well per RFC 1123 but AFAIK those aren't really seen in the wild.

Comment: citation needed re: total length restriction of an email address.

Comment: The length isn't that important. I know with multiple subdomains the length automatically increases, however; the only thing important for me is the amount of subdomain levels you can have, as they won't be extremely long anyway. Also, 30 levels is not something I would even do. Not even 10. Maybe just 3/4 max. But it was also a big curiousity I had (note: I'm no expert on servers and domains).

Comment: Added argument and citation for maximum email address length, @Alnitak