# How do web hosting sites like 000webhost create multiple free domains?

Tags: web-server, web-hosting, website, dns-hosting

I don't know if this is the right place to ask but, the other day I hosted my website in 000webhost, and they gave me the free domain [www.mywebsitename.000webhost.com](http://www.mywebsitename.000webhost.com). How does that work? And if I register my own domain name can I create multiple websites in the format [www.newwebsite.mydomainname.com](http://www.newwebsite.mydomainname.com)?

Comment: Every domain owner (for instance example.com) can create unlimited sub domains (`*.example.com` and `*.*.example.com` and nearly unlimited sub levels ) and then it is a question of configuration in your webserver(s) to show the correct content

Comment: @HermanB: for the *nearly unlimited sub levels*, there are some limitations, which I have calculated in my answer on [Amount of allowed subdomains in domain and email](https://serverfault.com/a/841282/274176). That's highly theoretical, though. :)